# how to get time from php class?

Tags: php, class

Below is a part of class file:

```
class Main{
public time;
$this->time = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s",time()+21600);
}
```

But it is showing the following error:

```
syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_FUNCTION in /home/user/folder/Main.php on line 3
```

Would someone tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot a `$` for the `time` variable and the `assignment` of the value you can do in the `__construct()` function like this:

```
<?php
    class Main {
        public $time;

        function __construct() {
            $this->time = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s",time()+21600);
        }
    }
    $object = new Main();
    echo $object->time;
?>
```

Output:

```
2014-11-27 11:43:36
```

Also good to know is that you only can assign constant values to a class member in the class definition! In the constructor you can assign whatever you want

See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Comment: That's how to do it. It was not a mere typo `$`, that code needed a constructor as well.

Comment: Actually in main code, the $ sign exists. I wrote it wrong mistakenly here.

Comment: @stockBoi then you only have to put the assignment in the constructor! See the explanation at the end of the answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can't add code directly in your function. It must be inside it's method.
There are several ways to achieve this. I'm showing one of that through Construtor and get methods:

```
class Main{
    private $time;

    function __construct(){
        $this->time = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s",time()+21600);
    }

    public function getTime(){
        return $this->time;
    }
}

$obj = new Main();
$time = $obj->getTime();
echo $time;
```

First know fundamentals of Object Oriented Programming.

Comment: Spent some effort to write both those methods instead of a simple constructor, but didn't spend a second to call the `setTime()` method before getting the time? This will output blank

Comment: Sorry it's a mistake I'm changing it.